# JMeter Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release

Tags: javascript, java, jmeter, nashorn, deprecation-warning

When I run JMeter 5.1.1 recently downloaded, I see many times in `terminal window`:

> Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK
> release

I've used web search and found [JEP 335: Deprecate the Nashorn JavaScript Engine](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335).

> Motivation

> The Nashorn JavaScript engine was first incorporated into
> JDK 8 via JEP 174 as a replacement for the Rhino scripting engine.
> When it was released, it was a complete implementation of the
> ECMAScript-262 5.1 standard.
>
> With the rapid pace at which ECMAScript language constructs, along
> with APIs, are adapted and modified, we have found Nashorn challenging
> to maintain.

I expected to read that new engine is now in more use, but no, I could not find what will run JavaScript in replacement. What would happen with JavaScript in JMeter? It will not run and we use *encouraged* to use Groovy?

BTW, how to remove that warning from terminal?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Groovy is [encouraged](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) in JMeter's best practices

> We advise using Apache Groovy

In new version [changes](https://apache.github.io/jmeter-site-preview/site/changes.html) there's a workaround for this warning:

> To silence these warnings, add -Dnashorn.args=--no-deprecation-warning to your Java arguments. That can be achieved by setting the enviroment variable JVM_ARGS
>
> ```
> export JVM_ARGS="-Dnashorn.args=--no-deprecation-warning"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Even better, you can use:

```
static {
  System.setProperty("nashorn.args","--no-deprecation-warning");
}
```

Do this **before** you instantiate the `ScriptEngineManager` Object and you'll be set! No warnings and it's in your code instead of just your launch environment!

Answer (score 0):

You may also install Rhino, see note on https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html#Known%20problems%20and%20workarounds

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that the Java Development Kit (JDK)'s Nashorn JavaScript engine is scheduled to be removed in a later JDK version. The notice indicates that Nashorn will no longer be supported in future JDK versions, thus you should begin moving your code to use an alternate JavaScript engine, like GraalVM or another appropriate choice. This is part of Oracle's effort to streamline and improve the JDK by removing deprecated or less-used components.